# Convert portion of string to datetime in C#

Tags: c#

I have two parameters defined in appsettings.json of an asp.net core project.

```
  "TimeParam": {
    "StartTime": "00:00:00.0001",
    "EndTime": "23:59:99.999"
    "BackOffDay": 1
  },
```

In a function, I need to pass two parameters as startDate and endDate of data type date.

For example, for the startDate I need to be like `17/06/2020 00:00:00.0001` and the endDate to be like `17/06/2020 23:59:99.999`

How can I get to set the two variable as follows taking into consideration the time that I have set in the appsettings.json?

```
StartDate: DateTime.Now.AddDays(BackOffDay) EndDate: DateTime.Now
```

Comment: `var startDate = DateTime.Parse($"{DateTime.Now.AddDays(BackOffDay):dd/MM/yyyy} {StartTime}");` and similarly for `endDate`.

Comment: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: Is your culture set for day/month/year? If not, you can use [ParseExact()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=netcore-3.1) instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You tricked me a second there, `23:59:99.999` is no parseable time as there are only 59 seconds in a minute.

But here you go:

```
using System;           
using System.Globalization;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var start= "00:00:00.0001";
        var end = "23:59:59.999";
        int backOffDay = 1;
        
        var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(start);
        var endTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(end);
        
        var startTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(backOffDay).Add(startTimeSpan);
        var endTime = DateTime.Now.Date.AddDays(backOffDay).Add(endTimeSpan);
        
        Console.WriteLine(startTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss.FFFF"));
        Console.WriteLine(endTime.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss.FFFF"));
    }
}
```

You can test it with [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6ULJYt).

> 19/06/2020 0:00:00.0001
>
> 19/06/2020 23:59:59.999

P.S.: To make sure all timestamps are always parsed the same, you might want to do something like this as well:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
```

or just for a single call:

```
var culture = new CultureInfo("en-US");
var startTimeSpan = TimeSpan.Parse(start, culture);
```

Although parsing seemed to work well with en-US culture I wouldn't guarantee it does in all enivronments.

Comment: Thanks for this beautiful answer!. Is `var end = "23:59:59.9999";` or it should only contain three `999` correct ?

Comment: You're welcome - I updated my answer and the fiddle to use ".FFFF" instead of ".ffff". This will omit trailing zeros. P.S.: You didn't clearly specify "backOffDate", if you want it to be one day ago just use `-1 * backOffDay` instead of `backOffDay`.

Answer (score 2):

Use [DateTime.Now.Date](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.date?view=netcore-3.1), then add the start and end time to create the start date and end date respectively. Use [TimeSpan.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan.parse?view=netcore-3.1) to parse the times.

```
(DateTime.Now.Date + TimeSpan.Parse("13:01:05")).ToString();
//2020-06-18 13:01:05
```

Comment: I need to concatenate the date and time together. And then obtain the datetime as `17/06/2020 00:00:00.0001`

Comment: @CadaMerx Adding the date-portion of a DateTime and a timespan does exactly that.

Comment: An example please ?

Comment: @CadaMerx just do what JonasH suggested, then either print the date time or debug and inspect it's value. It will have the times you want on the current date.